# Openshift Apache/Nginx 405 not allowed

Tags: apache, nginx, openshift

We are using `OpenShift 3.4`. Using a `s2i` PHP image for pod. When doing a `curl` from pod to an external resource it's returning `405 Not Allowed nginx/1.16.1`. The code is running fine on the local setup. As I understood from web, it's due to the fact our own server is not allowing `POST` request and we need to configure it to allow the same.

```
$ch = curl_init($ldapAuthURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I am unable to resolve this, since I don't have any experience with `OpenShift` I tried looking for `httpd` file but it's to be found no where. The support team is not able to help either, they are saying they support image pushing and pulling only and it's our application code that is faulty.

Comment: Apache? Nginx? I don't get how _both_ the names in the question and in the tags are coming together. You're only mentioning nginx in the text - please clarify or edit tags/title

Comment: It should be using `Apache` to serve files, I also see few `.htaccess` files, but the error message is returning `Nginx/1.16.1` so I am really confused, owing to he limited server configuration knowledge. I am hoping that Nginx is being used to serve static files and `Apache` as a regular server to serve php files.

Answer (score 1):

To my dismay support team was right, It was an application issue. My team member has configured the URL of the frontend which was running an angular app on `nginx`. Hence the cryptic error `405 nginx` since the frontend won't support post requests on that URL.

That's why there were no Nginx config files in the PHP pod since it was using `Apache` to serve the files.

Steps to resolve:

1. I created a standalone curl service in PHP using the public URL.
2. It worked. Then I was sure there's some issue with my application code
3. I tried standalone curl with the URL PHP was hitting, it returned the same 405 error.
4. It gave a clear result there's some issue with the URL